# Integrating full calendar plugin with angular 12 design not loading

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, fullcalendar

I'm trying to implement the [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) plugin in my angular project.

Below is the code
Module

```
    import { FullCalendarModule } from '@fullcalendar/angular'; // must go before plugins
    import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'; // a plugin!
    import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'; // a plugin!
    
    FullCalendarModule.registerPlugins([ // register FullCalendar plugins
      dayGridPlugin,
      interactionPlugin
    ]);

@NgModule({
  imports: [
      CommonModule,
      FormsModule,
      FullCalendarModule
     
  ],
```

Below is the code in component.ts

```
import { CalendarOptions } from '@fullcalendar/angular';
calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
  };
```

the project also has bootstrap 3.7

When I run the project the design for FullCalendar is not loading.
I can see the style loading in the index.html but its not working.

Please Guide.
Attaching an image for reference
[image]

Comment: Are you getting any error in console?

Comment: No Error in console

Comment: @ShrutiNair Can You share more details of your project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add fullcalendar [stylesheet](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/initialize-es6) inside angular.json styles array

**angular.json**

```
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss",
          "node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.css",
          "node_modules/@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css"
        ],
```

Comment: Thanks. I used common/main.css and daygrid/main.css